# Test Template with Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am attempting to utilize the Robot Framework Test Template function and have been experiencing a little difficulty.

My current Test consist of opening 5 different websites (declared as variables)

Here is my code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Library  OperatingSystem
Library  String
Library  Collections
Test Template  Open URL

*** Variables ***
${URL1}     http://montrealgazette.com/
${URL2}     https://www.usatoday.com/
${URL3}     http://www.foxnews.com/
${URL4}     http://www.cnn.com/
${URL5}     https://ca.reuters.com/

*** Test Cases ***
Validate Availability
${URL1}
${URL2}
${URL3}
${URL4}
${URL5}

*** Keywords ***
Open URL
[Arguments]  ${URL}
Open Browser    $[URL]     Chrome
```

When I run this code, 5 separate blank browser windows are opened.If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You are using which library of selenium.. ? Java or selenium.. ?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the omission. I am'm using Robot Framework with Python and Selenium2Library.

Comment: Do you _want_ five separate windows, or do you want a single window? If you're just testing availability, do you need any windows at all? You can just do a REST request to the page to see if it's available.

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please check once if it might help you...

Comment: @BryanOakley : If possible, I would prefer to not have a window at all. How can I implement a REST request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't seem to have indented your test case's content, which could perhaps be the problem (after you've fixed the syntax error mentioned in [Raj sattam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47352837/8332700)). That's pretty much the only mistake I can see. You'll want to do the same in your keyword's declaration as well.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Validate Availability
    ${URL1}
    ${URL2}
    ${URL3}
    ${URL4}
    ${URL5}
```

If that still doesn't fix it, instead of using the `** Settings **` section, you may try to declare the test case itself as a templated test case, like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Library  OperatingSystem
Library  String
Library  Collections

*** Variables ***
${URL1}     http://montrealgazette.com/
${URL2}     https://www.usatoday.com/
${URL3}     http://www.foxnews.com/
${URL4}     http://www.cnn.com/
${URL5}     https://ca.reuters.com/

*** Test Cases ***
Validate Availability
    [Template]    Open URL
    ${URL1}
    ${URL2}
    ${URL3}
    ${URL4}
    ${URL5}

*** Keywords ***
Open URL
    [Arguments]  ${URL}
    Open Browser    ${URL}     Chrome
```

Comment: Thank you @Verv , the secondary issue I experienced was due to lack of indentation. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [Execute Javascript](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Execute%20Javascript) Keyword like:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Library  OperatingSystem
Library  String
Library  Collections
Test Template  Open URL

*** Variables ***
${URL1}     http://montrealgazette.com/
${URL2}     https://www.usatoday.com/
${URL3}     http://www.foxnews.com/
${URL4}     http://www.cnn.com/
${URL5}     https://ca.reuters.com/

*** Test Cases ***
Validate Availability
    Open URLs In New Tab   ${URL1}    ${URL2}    ${URL3}    ${URL4}    ${URL5}

*** Keywords ***
Open URLs In New Tab   
    [Arguments]  @{URL}
    :FOR ${eachUrl}  IN  @{URL}
    \   Execute Javascript    window.open(${eachUrl},"_blank");
```

Comment: Why would you do this instead of using one of the built-in keywords?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley... which built in keyword you are talking about... ? As far as I know there is no such keyword for the same...

Comment: Either way that doesn't answer OP's question at all.

Comment: @MayurAgarwal : Thanks for the help, but i'm not really interested in using Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The only part you need to change is the *** Keywords *** section

```
*** Keywords ***
Open URL
    [Arguments]  ${URL}
    Open Browser    ${URL}     Chrome
```

Instead of **square brackets** use **braces**

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, feel like i'm getting somewhere now, but I receive the following error for each case : Validate Availability                                                 | FAIL |
Test case contains no keywords.${URL1}                                                               | FAIL |
Test case contains no keywords.${URL2}

Comment: Thanks @Raj sattam . You're answer brought me  1 step closer to answering this question. I also have problems with indentation that were addressed in a followup answer.

Comment: Glad my answer helped. I thought indentation is fine because you mentioned that it's open 5 blank Crome window. Anyway I would suggest you to have two different files. One for your resources (i.e your Variables and Keywords) and a separate test case file. Just import your resources in test case file. Follow this demo url.https://bitbucket.org/robotframework/webdemo