# How to pass command line arguments (test data parameters) in Robot framework

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, robotframework

I want to run my test case with multiple test data (for different countries). Can this be achieved in the Robot framework? I have been working on RIDE IDE.

Below is sample code:

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup    Login to Application 
Suite TearDown    Logout and Close The Browser
Resource     import all required resource files 

***Test Cases ***
Sample Test Case To Create Data for Multiple countries 
     Select Country      USA       #here am hard coding the country value, instead I want to pass it in run time 
     Enter all required data 
     Click Submit

    #sample resource file that has the keyword for selecting Country Drop down and fill other details
    *** Keywords ***
    Select Country
    [Arguments]       ${value} 
    Select From List By Label    ${locator}    ${value}
    Input Text      locator    text value
```

I tried to pass the arguments in test case but it says sanity check fails. Reset changes in the RIDE IDE the moment I add arguments at the Test case level.

I am using Python 2.7.14,  RIDE 2.0a1.

Comment: You mean loop data ?

Comment: no i want to run test cases individually for a country instead of looping and also instead of hard coding and changing the country value every time before running the test cases

Answer (score 22):

In the Robot Framework Userguide there is an entire chapter on [Configuring the Execution](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#configuring-execution) of Robot Framework. In this chapter there is a section on [passing variables via the command line](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-variables).

An example:

```
robot --variable OS:Linux --variable IP:10.0.0.42 my_test_suite_file.robot
```

and then you can use the variables `${OS}` and `${IP}` at any point in your scripts as they are Global variables.

Comment: yes I have gone through this but when i try to pass the Arguments in Test case it throws me error cant save the changes. so My question is can't we have Arguments in Test case directly ? i am able to keep Arguments in keywords but not in Test case

Answer (score 7):

Add a variable with the target country, use it in the case, and set its value on run start. Only the relevant parts of your code:

```
# put this just after the end of the Settings section
*** Variables ***
${country}    USA

*** Test Cases ***
Sample Test Case To Create Data for Multiple countries 
    Select Country      ${country}
    # the rest of your code
```

If your run it as is, it will use "USA" as value; if you want to override, pass the other value on the CLI:

```
 robot --variable country:Mexico your_file.robot
```

Comment: I am using RIDE IDE when I type Variables in Test case file it throws me an error pop up "Error: Sanity check failed. Reset changes" i am unable to add variables in test case file and also arguments in Test case.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with RIDE ¯\_(ツ)_/¯; you might have hit a bug in it - though I'm only guessing here. Try the approach by editing the file with a simple text editor, see does it work for you.

Comment: I have 2 requirements to run from Jenkins and to run in local before i start running in Jenkins i need to run successfully in local. 
I am using RIDE IDE to write and run my scripts in Local. When I try to pass the country variable in arguments fields in Ride IDE it throws error 
can you help me how i can pass this variable as argument.

Comment: "How to Pass command line arguments (test data parameters) in Robot framework?" - that's how; "Why RIDE IDE throws an error in your environment?" - I cannot comment on that, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pybot command, use one of the bellow Syntaxes

```
pybot --variable Variable:Value ScriptName.txt
```

OR

```
pybot -v Variable:Value ScriptName.txt
```

Multiple Variable

```
pybot -v Variable1:Value -v Variable2:Value ScriptName.txt
```

You can access the command line variable value directly in your script without declaring and re-assigning.

Example.

```
pybot -v userId:admin -v password:123admin123 testLoginScript.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A good approach for a task of this nature, is to use Templates.  See [Test Template with Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351704/test-template-with-robot-framework/47352837#47352837)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Dumping the link without an explanation is rarely helpful.